# ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException on insertion in the partitioned table using spring data jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, database-partitioning

We have implemented the partitioning on a Postgres table using a flyway script.

In the flyway script, we are also creating a trigger defined as below -

```
CREATE TRIGGER raw_event_insert_or_partition
BEFORE INSERT
ON public.raw_event
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.raw_event_insert_or_partition();
```

public.raw_event_insert_or_partition() creates a partition if not exist and do the insertion.

Below is the complete flyway script for the reference -

```
            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.parcel_event_insert_partition()
            RETURNS trigger
            LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
            COST 100
            VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
        AS $BODY$
        
        DECLARE
          partition_date TEXT;
          partition TEXT;
          start_ts TIMESTAMP ;
          end_ts TIMESTAMP ;
        BEGIN
          partition_date := to_char(NEW.carrier_status_time_gmt,'YYYY_MM_01');
          start_ts := partition_date::timestamp ;
          end_ts := start_ts + interval '1 month' ;
          partition := TG_RELNAME || '_' || to_char(start_ts,'YYYY_MM_01') || '_' || to_char(end_ts,'YYYY_MM_01');
        
          IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname=partition) THEN
            EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE '    || quote_ident(partition)
                || ' (check (carrier_status_time_gmt >= ''' || start_ts || ''' '
                || '     AND carrier_status_time_gmt <  ''' || end_ts || ''')) '
                || ' INHERITS (' || TG_RELNAME || ');';
            EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ON ' || quote_ident(partition) || ' (carrier_status_time_gmt,carrier_code,value)';
            RAISE NOTICE 'A partition has been created %', partition;
          END IF;
          EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(partition) || ' SELECT(' || TG_RELNAME || ' ' || quote_literal(NEW) || ').* RETURNING id;';
          RETURN NULL;
        END;
        $BODY$;
        -- Register TRIGGER
        
        CREATE TRIGGER parcel_event_insert_or_partition
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON public.parcel_event
            FOR EACH ROW
            EXECUTE FUNCTION public.parcel_event_insert_partition();
```

When we are running the insertion query in the PgAdmin console, it's working fine and data is getting inserted in the expected partition.

But when we are trying to insert the data using the **save()** method of the crudRepository we are getting the below error -

```
org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1;
```

On enabling show_sql we are getting the below queries in the logs-

```
 Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
 Hibernate: insert into parcel_event (carrier_code, 
 carrier_status, carrier_status_code, carrier_status_time_gmt, 
 carrier_sub_status, carrier_sub_status_code, 
 carrier_sub_status_description, destination_location, 
 extra_info, status, status_code, status_description, 
 sub_status, sub_status_code, sub_status_description, 
 last_updated_at, latitude, location_code, location_name, 
 longitude, order_no, org_id, previous_status, 
 previous_status_time, status_identifier_value, 
  status_received_at, type, value, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you enable the "show_sql" flag and share the statement Hibernate is running? Do you get the same error if you insert the entity with EntityManager.persist()?

Comment: @Augusto I have added in the question description please check.

Comment: The query and the error don't match. ` ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` is thrown on updates, but your are doing an insert. I suggest you to throw away spring-jpa and use an entitymanager directly as this could be a problem of using spring rather than hibernate. The problem with spring jpa is that `save()` might do an EntityManager.persist() or merge() and with JPA (at least for me) it's good to be explicit about what operation you want to run as they can product subtle errors.

Comment: @Augusto found something similar here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475235/table-partitioning-with-jpa-throws-optimisticlockexception
Do you think the same issue I might be facing?